# I can't adjust cart pages when It's empty in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart, cart, opencart-module

I started to learn opencart 3-4 days ago. Anyway My problem is I can't adjust cart page when the basket is empty.

I mean I have no problem to  İf I throw one product in a basket. But if I didn't throw and İf I click complete shopping, the problem is here. I can't find the html this section. So I can't edit here.

İf I throw one product and click complete shopping, it's okay I can adjust here.

[image: first picture]

But İf I didn't throw any product and click complete shopping. How can I adjust here. I can't find any tpl files in this section. I deleted everyone but this picture never changed. I haven't a good english. I hope, I can tell :). Thank you for helping..

[image]

Comment: go to catalog/view/theme/your theme/template/error/not_found.tpl, to manage if Your shopping cart is empty!

Comment: really thanks. İt's work :)

Comment: Can I ask one thing ? I create a variable for about us in footer.php like this $data['information'] = $this->url->link('information/information');   But if I click about us the page I just see not found information page. But url is true. Where my mistake ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to catalog/view/theme/your theme/template/common/footer.tpl , add below code it will show Information List.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
      <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

If you only want to add **About us link**, add below code in catalog/view/theme/your theme/template/common/footer.tpl

```
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <?php foreach ($informations as $information) { if($information['title']=="About Us") { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
      <?php } } ?>
    </ul>
```

Hope this helps you!